# How to include value of an input field with date type of HTML5 in serialize form

Tags: javascript, serialization

how can I include a date type input field in HTML5 whenever I will use serialization to get all the values of my form? when I look at the console the date is not included in the serialized form. Below is my javascript function:

```
 $('#submit').click(function(){
      var item_data = $('#itemForm').serialize();
      console.log(item_data);
  });
```

Below is my form:

```
<form id="itemForm">
     <input type="text" name="item[item_name]">
     <input type="text" name="item[item_desc]">
     <input type="date" name="item[date_acquired]">
     <input type="date" name="item[expiration_date]">
    <button id="submit">Save</button>
</form>
```

Comment: What version of jQuery? There's a bug on html 5 on versions 1.4 and below.

Comment: @DenisAli is probably right, your code works fine in jQuery 2.1.3 https://jsfiddle.net/s9hnhkfc/

Comment: Your code also works fine to me. Like what other recommends you to do, pls check your JQuery version cococ martin :).